# Remove last Comma from while loop

Tags: php

My code is resulting in a output like this

Title1,1,Title2,2,

How can i remove the last comma from this?

```
$comma = ",";

$query = "SELECT name, listid FROM playlist ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while(list($name, $listid) = $result->fetch_row()) {
    echo $name;
    echo $comma;
    echo $listid;
echo $comma;
}
```

Comment: Don't `echo` your last `$comma`.

Comment: rtrim() http://php.net/rtrim

Comment: @user3140296 : See example here: https://eval.in/85496

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$lines = array();

while(list($name, $listid) = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $lines[] = "$name,$listid";
}

echo implode(',', $lines);
```

Comment: I prefer this method to the one I posted, as it allows you to potentially manipulate the data even more, by sorting etc... Nice one!

Answer (score 8):

Don't manually echo commas.  Just make an array, then `implode` it.

```
echo implode(',', array($name, $listid));
```

Comment: This answer is flat out wrong. Look at my answer. The OP wants a comma between the different rows; they just don't want the very last one.

Comment: @JosephSilber: Either way, `implode` should hopefully point them in the right direction.  It wasn't 100% clear to me what he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use trim

```
<?php
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,";
echo trim($str, ",");
```

**Output**

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$query = "SELECT name, listid FROM playlist ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$data = array();
while(list($name, $listid) = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $data[] = $name.",".$listid;
}

echo implode(',', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $comma = ",";
    $html = ""; 

    $query = "SELECT name, listid FROM playlist ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    while(list($name, $listid) = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $html .= $name.$comma.$listid.$comma;   
    }

   echo substr($html, 0, strlen($html) - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with Joseph Silber's answer, although this would work :

```
$comma = ",";
$k=0;
$query = "SELECT name, listid FROM playlist ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while(list($name, $listid) = $result->fetch_row()) {
    if($k!=0){
     echo $comma;
    }
    echo $name;
    echo $comma;
    echo $listid;        
    $k++;
}
```

Comment: Too much compute for such a little task - although it does solve the issue, *I guess* :)

Comment: Easier if you reverse the logic, and put out a comma __before__ echoing name, etc for every row except the very first

Comment: This seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$num_rows= mysqli_num_rows($result);
$ctr=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$ctr++;
    echo $row['example'];
    if($ctr!=$num_rows){
        echo ',';}
    else{
        echo '';
    }
}
```